# Cannot pass a SQL Update query, may be problems with DatePicker format

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, azure, datepicker

I keep having trouble updating a table in my database, which is hosted on Azure.

I keep running into problems with a certain SQL statement.

Here goes: I read out several columns of information about a tool, depending on the equipmentId that is given. 
The textboxes will be shown with all the information that is currently in the database. If the user elects to change anything he just deletes what is currently in one of the textboxes, for example registration number, enters something else, and hits the submit button.

When submitted, all the text from the textboxes should be sent into the database, no matter if they have been changed or not. It just overwrites everything. 
I can read out everything, so there is no trouble with the connection, but I'm having a hard time writing it back in.

Here is the code:

[image]

The datePurchase.Text is a string, gotten from a wpf datepicker, not a textbox. The column on azure is of type DateTime. I dont know if they are able to match the dates though, as that is where the error message is saying that something is wrong. I am in Norway, so my date looks like this 02.03.2015.

Comment: There is no good reason to post code as a series of images, and a lot of good reasons not to. Please [edit] your question to include the code in indented code blocks.

Comment: Don't you think some of your values should be in quotes, especially the date?

Comment: Why on earth would you think that linking to pictures of your code is the right thing to do?

Comment: @Nathan: You just made my evening.

Comment: @abatishchev: You're … welcome, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

As @codingbiz said, you are missing some quotes in there.

The only reason it says the date is the issue is because the other ones are potentially valid SQL, but they are not. 
Wrap the date in quotes and you will see new errors. Tektroniks, TEST, oscilloscope, and the date need to be surrounded with single quotes. i.e. 'TEST'.

If you aren't familiar with SQL, you may want to look into something to abstract it away, like entity framework. At the very least I would pick up a book on SQL if you are going to have to be working with it.

Also I've found the best thing to do when there is a SQL issue, is to take the command you are sending and try to execute it in SSMS directly.

Answer (score -1):

If this is SQL Server try converting from "dd.MM.yyyy" to "yy-MM-dd" in single quote.
I recommend parsing to DateTime first to validate and then printing to appropriate date format for DB. See [DateTime.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Parse1_Example).

For example:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(datePurchase.Text);
var purchaseDate = String.Format("'{0}'", theDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: Do you mean pass a DataTime object to server, or a formatted string? The former is correct, the later is not.